# Dagger2 Multiscope with subcomponents

Tags: android, dagger-2

First, I will briefly explain the setup of my project. I have 4 scopes in my project:

1. `@Singleton`
2. `@ActivityScope`
3. `@ScreenScope` - For controllers/fragments
4. `@ChildScreenScope` - Nested controllers inside Screenscope

My activity, screen, and child screen are subcomponents.

Let's say I have an `ErrorHandler` class that could be used in a fragment or child fragment. What is the best way to inject/provide this dependency?

Currently, I provide from Screen component, however, I want child screens to have their own instance. If I provide from both screen and child screen components, it won't work because subcomponents inherit from their parent and I get an error for multiple bindings.

Comment: If the @provides method is not annotated with the screen scope, then resolving instances of the ErrorHandler will always result in a new instance of ErrorHandler in Screen and Childscreen components

Answer (score 0):

When the type alone is insufficient to identify a dependency, you could use [`@Named`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Named.html). Following your example, this could look like:

```
@Module
class ScreenModule {
    @ScreenScope
    @Provides
    @Named("screen")
    fun provideErrorHandler(): ErrorHandler = ErrorHandler()
}

@Module
class ChildScreenModule {
    @ChildScreenScope
    @Provides
    @Named("child")
    fun provideErrorHandler(): ErrorHandler = ErrorHandler()
}

class MyScreen : Fragment() {
    @Inject @Named("screen") lateinit var errorHandler: ErrorHandler
    ...
}

class MyChildScreen : Fragment() {
    @Inject @Named("child") lateinit var errorHandler: ErrorHandler
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using scopes does have the DoubleCheck cost. I would just use @Named without any scopes. Child screens would get new instance of ErrorHandler for each injection.

Comment: Just to clarify, DoubleCheck is on the factory instance providing the ErrorHandler.